# Determine if 2 lists with similar objects contain a partial duplicate

Tags: java, performance

I have two lists of `Person` objects. I need to compare the lists to determine if items in `list1` exist in `list2` and vice versa.

This is not a straight `equals()` scenario as the objects are not the same, but may have identical field values. It is those values that I need to compare.

Currently, I am using Java 8's `Streams` API to return either a match or `null`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> originalPeople = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Person> newPeople = new ArrayList<>();

        originalPeople.add(new Person("William", "Tyndale"));
        originalPeople.add(new Person("Jonathan", "Edwards"));
        originalPeople.add(new Person("Martin", "Luther"));

        newPeople.add(new Person("Jonathan", "Edwards"));
        newPeople.add(new Person("James", "Tyndale"));
        newPeople.add(new Person("Roger", "Moore"));

        // Create a list of people that no longer exist in the new list
        for (Person original : originalPeople) {
            if (getPersonInList(
                    newPeople, original.getFirstName(), original.getLastName()) == null) {
                System.out.printf("%s %s is not in the new list!%n",
                        original.getFirstName(), original.getLastName());
            }
        }
    }

    private static Person getPersonInList(
            final List<Person> list, final String firstName, final String lastName) {

        return list.stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))
                .filter(t -> t.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName))
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}

class Person {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

In my real-world application, however, both lists have over 30,000 items and this is very time-consuming.

Is there a better way to perform this comparison? I would want this to work both ways as well, so if there are items in `newPeople` that were not in `originalPeople`, I would want that list as well.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919387/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-arraylists

Comment: No, because that does not in any way address my original question. I am not trying to simple compare the 2 lists and locate/remove identical objects.

Comment: Is this an MCVE? Because that's SO territory, at Code Review we need to see the real deal or we'll come with suggestions not applicable to your code. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @mast However, my code is working just fine, so SO is not the place for this.

Comment: That's not what I meant. **Lacks concrete context:** Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: In your example code, the person class consists *exactly* of the two fields you compare and therefore this is a perfect example for `equals()` with a generic standard implementation. Thus, your question contradicts your code. As Mast already told you: lacking concrete context.

Answer (score 3):

There are certain reasons I would not prefer your approach. These are:

1) There are multiple method calls which reduces the readability.

2) You are using filter twice which decreases the performances. You could do it inside the same `filter` like I've shown below

3) With this approach you don't have a consolidated `List` which contains common elements. For that you need another `else` condition which increases the cyclomatic complexity.

4) A `null` check which could produce NPE if not handled carefully as you are using `findFirst()` which returns `Optional` (Although `null` can be replaced with default `new Person("","")` object which is again not recommended).

5) Finally don't use `ArrayList<Person> originalPeople = new ArrayList<>();`; rather declare as `List`, to follow [*programming to interface*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java).

Rather I would use below approach:

```
private static List<Person> getPersonInList(
            final List<Person> newPeople, List<Person> originalPeople) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();

        newPeople.forEach(p ->
                originalPeople.stream()
                              .filter(p1 -> p.getFirstName().equals(p1.getFirstName()) && 
                                      p.getLastName().equals(p1.getLastName()))
                              .forEach(list::add));
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: This is still double iteration right? O(n*n)?

Comment: how come this answer has more votes?

Answer (score 3):

#### The approach, algorithm

To find if an object exists in a list, you need to perform a linear search,
potentially visiting every single element, in \$O(n)\$ time.
More efficient data structures exist:

- Use an *ordered* data structure: if the values are sorted, then you can find if an element exists using binary search, in \$O(\log n)\$ time.
- Use a *hashset*: you can find if an element is in the set in constant time, \$O(1)\$

To be to search efficiently, use a hashset instead of a list.
However, to be able to use a hashset efficiently,
it is required that the objects you put in it have appropriate implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

See the [official tutorial on the `Object` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html),
especially the sections on the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.
Note that IDEs like IntelliJ and Eclipse can generate these methods for you easily (they are boring to write by hand, and usually there's little reason to do so).

With correct implementation of the `equals` and `hashCode` methods,
for example as in the other [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/199990/12390) by @Teddy,
your main program could be reduced to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Person> originalPeople = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Person> newPeople = new HashSet<>();

    originalPeople.add(new Person("William", "Tyndale"));
    originalPeople.add(new Person("Jonathan", "Edwards"));
    originalPeople.add(new Person("Martin", "Luther"));

    newPeople.add(new Person("Jonathan", "Edwards"));
    newPeople.add(new Person("James", "Tyndale"));
    newPeople.add(new Person("Roger", "Moore"));

    for (Person original : originalPeople) {
        if (!newPeople.contains(original)) {
            System.out.printf("%s %s is not in the new list!%n",
                    original.getFirstName(), original.getLastName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists are linear in terms of performance. You are iterating original list, which cannot be avoided. But, for each item in original you are iterating the new list looking for a match. This is bad for performance.

You should just add all the new data to a HashSet. Then iterate the original list and check if the HashSet contains that pair.

To use a HashSet, the main thing is the hash function. If the person class can be made to have a hashCode only relating the firstName and the lastName, then you can go with that option.

If not just use a Pair. Its a standard tuple, and one should be available in some of the collections already in your project classpath.

```
public class PersonsMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> originalPeople = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Person> newPeople = new ArrayList<>();

        originalPeople.add(new Person("William", "Tyndale", 30));
        originalPeople.add(new Person("Jonathan", "Edwards", 31));
        originalPeople.add(new Person("Martin", "Luther", 32));

        newPeople.add(new Person("Jonathan", "Edwards", 33));
        newPeople.add(new Person("James", "Tyndale", 34));
        newPeople.add(new Person("Roger", "Moore", 35));

        //Prepare
        HashSet<Person> newGuys = new HashSet<>();
        for(Person newPerson:newPeople) {
            newGuys.add(newPerson);
        }

        //Results
        for(Person originalPerson:originalPeople) {
            if(!newGuys.contains(originalPerson)) {
                System.out.println("This person is not in the new list: " 
                        + originalPerson.getFirstName() + " " 
                        + originalPerson.getLastName() );
            }
        }
    }

    static class Person {

        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;
        //Extra field age to remind you that it should not be included in hashCode and equals
        private final int age;

        Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.age = age;
        }

        String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }


        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            //Auto-generated by Eclipse.
            //Important that this hash code use only the name fields.

            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            //Auto-generated by Eclipse.
            //Important that this hash code use only the name fields.

            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Person other = (Person) obj;
            if (firstName == null) {
                if (other.firstName != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
                return false;
            if (lastName == null) {
                if (other.lastName != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If those lists are not immutables then i would perfer to sort the lists and then traverse. 
Using stream you will always end up with complexicity of

> list1.size*list2.size

But if you can sort then it can be done in

> sort_complexicity(this should be list_size*log(list_size)) + list_size